# Finding the mass of 7cm string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, string

If a string has $120$ g and length $40$ cm.
I found that the linear mass density is given by $$120g/40cm=\ linear\ mass\ density$$

How do I use this to find the mass of a $7$cm of the same kind of string?

---

What I have done so far:
$$120g/40cm = m/7cm$$
$$m=7cm*120g/40cm$$
$$m = 21$$

Comment: ok, so what is the problem? Looks good to me.

Comment: For the people that down voted me. How is my question bad? I even provide my work, which happened to be correct, but I didn't know it was.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you're asking for someone to check your work, not asking a conceptual physics question. This is not a homework help site, and thus we discourage questions that are just asking for a review of existing work. Take a look at [our policy on homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is fine. Just don't forget the units in your final answer! (grams)